# ggplot2 Issue with stat_summary fun mean not plotting correctly within boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to add a mean to the boxplot, but the mean plots on the side, I cannot figure out how put the mean within the center of the boxplot itself. Please find an example code below.[boxplot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RMDZ.jpg)
Apologies if it has been previously asked, but I could not find anything on the topic.

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month, labels= c("May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"))

airquality_trimmed <- airquality[which(airquality$Month == "Jul" | airquality$Month == "Aug" |
                                         airquality$Month == "Sep"), ]
airquality_trimmed$Temp.f <- factor(ifelse(airquality_trimmed$Temp > mean(airquality_trimmed$Temp), 1, 0),
                                    labels = c("Low temp", "High temp"))


BP <- ggplot(airquality_trimmed, aes(x= Month, y= Ozone, fill= Temp.f))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha= 0.7)+
  scale_y_continuous(name= "Mean ozone in\nparts per billion") +
  scale_x_discrete(name= "Month")+
  stat_summary(fun= "mean", geom= "point", colour= "black")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent") +
  labs(fill = "Temperature")
BP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)` to the `stat_summary` call:

```r
ggplot(airquality_trimmed, aes(x= Month, y= Ozone, fill= Temp.f))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha= 0.7)+
  scale_y_continuous(name= "Mean ozone in\nparts per billion") +
  scale_x_discrete(name= "Month")+
  stat_summary(fun= "mean", geom= "point", colour= "black", position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent") +
  labs(fill = "Temperature")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>